# Persist Local UIWebView Values

Tags: javascript, objective-c, ios, uiwebview

****EDIT****
I've done more research and it looks like cookies may also be the answer. I suppose I would add a button to the form inside the embedded html that calls a function to create a cookie for the values. Then I could access this cookie through obj-c using the stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString method. Of course then you run into the issue of expiration, multiple copies of the form not being allowed, etc. So it is a trade-off of features. I'm going to stick with the window.location route because I can store this in a DB and then the user can create another instance of the same form
****EDIT****

I've done some research and I have a vague idea how to accomplish this, but I was curious if there was a better method.

I have a local copy of an html form loading in a UIWebView on this iPad app I am developing. The forms are submitted server-side through xml and parsed there for DB storage, but unfortunately they are pretty lengthy. So I want to let the user save the form in its current state (maybe they only fill it out halfway), and then return to it later.

What I am thinking is that I will have to write some javascript to parse the radio buttons and checkboxes in the form, then pass this data through the window.location trick to the obj-c code. But this is VERY lengthy, and the strings being passed back and forth between JS and Obj-C will be very long. Is there any other way to grab the values of these checkboxes/radio buttons and pass them to the obj-c side to be repopulated later?

Comment: Comment on the edit - its possible for another app (i.e. not your app) to **globally** turn off cookies (strange as that sounds, not sure if this is a bug or oversight or feature from Apple).

Comment: P.S. browsers put a limit on the size of cookies

Comment: would that disable cookies on a uiwebview using embedded html pages in the project? That just seems silly if it could really happen!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about going via a file? Save the settings/data to a file in JS and access that file in Objective-C land. But I guess you've already thought of this.

But at the end of the day the data has to be passed back and forth regardless of how you do it. Doing it via the window.location trick will be the fastest, and provided there are no limitations imposed by the OS itself is there any reason not to do it this way?

You could encode the data into a blob to make it easier to pass around.

But on the other hand doing it by file route may however be useful if you want the settings to persist if your app gets terminated.

Also you could actually submit the form data but intercept it in Objective-C before it gets sent by using a NSURLProtocol derived class.  THe NSURLProtocol class could allow the submission to proceed if it knows the data is complete. But I don't see any point in doing this if window.location doesn't have a size limit.

Comment: Ya I have decided to go the window.location hack route. It's not an unwieldy amount of data, just large enough to look annoying, but oh well. Thanks for your answer!